# Using a 360 rotation to drive another object so that it rotates 0-180 and then again 0-180

Tags: drivers, mathematics

I've got a bit of a remapping problem with my driver setup.

Driver disk rotates 360 degrees (or more)
Driven disk should match the driver for 0-180 degrees.
Driven disk should then rotate again from 0-180 degrees for the 180-360 degrees of the driver object.

Its basicly a question of mapping the rotation from one object to another
with the rule that the driven object is always rotating 0-180 degrees, never 180-360.

It would be especially great if this works for driver values beyond 360 as well.

Could this be done?
Im guessing it would need a scripted expression, but perhhaps there is a simpler way.[image]

Comment: Sounds like modulus. (remainder)  Blender uses radians as unit of angle   (have wrapped in degrees to demonstrate)  `degrees(radians(359) % pi)` returns 179 degrees, 360 ( a multiple of pi) flips it back to zero.

Comment: Hi batFINGER, thanks for taking the time to reply.
Ive used "degrees(radians(var) % pi)" with var being the input variable.

It seems to have a 1:1 connection with the driver. But sometimes It does jump to a different degree. Quite strange. It my setup it doesnt flip back to zero. Autorun python scripts is enable. Could I be overlooking something?

modulo seems fine to me

Comment: NP.  Is modulo a good fit?  ... requires  input rotation  is a single property, since rotation channels often do a mapping for us.

Comment: only used `degrees` to  output in degrees, would use `angle % pi` in driver expression, where angle is some rotation, natively in radians.

Comment: Perhaps the expression you're looking for is `(r%pi)+(pi*(r<0))`, ? ..  which is the same as @batFINGER 's , but keeps the rotations in phase immediately around 0.

Comment: Angle % pi works perfectly.
Thank you batFINGER and Robin Betts!